# Adding columns with condition check on row name

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dataframe

I am having troubles adding column conditionally to a df.  For instance, I would like to add class values to column VarB and VarC according to the value of Var A.

For instance, I would like to add 'yes' to VarB when VarA equals "a", "c" and "e" and "no" when it equals "b" and "d".  Also, I would like to add "1" to  VarC when VarA equals "a" or "e"; "2" to VarC when VarA equals "b" or "d"; and, "3" to VarC when VarA equals "c".

```
VarA
 a     
 b     
 c     
 d     
 e
```

Any tips?

Comment: Put your code, it will help to help you

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could be useful

```
DF <- data.frame(VarA=letters[1:4]) # this is your data.frame
    VarA
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d

DF$VarB <- ifelse(VarA %in% c('a','c','e'), 'yes', 'no')
DF$VarC <- ifelse(VarA %in% c('a','e'), 1, ifelse(VarA %in% c('b','d'),2,3))
DF
  VarA VarB VarC
1    a  yes    1
2    b   no    2
3    c  yes    3
4    d   no    2
```

You can use `transform` function as well.

```
DF <- data.frame(VarA=letters[1:4])
transform(DF, 
          VarB=ifelse(VarA %in% c('a','c','e'), 'yes', 'no'), 
          VarC=ifelse(VarA %in% c('a','e'), 1, ifelse(VarA %in% c('b','d'),2,3)))
  VarA VarB VarC
1    a  yes    1
2    b   no    2
3    c  yes    3
4    d   no    2
```

Comment: Perfect use of `transform()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do something in the spirit of the following:

```
cond1 <- data$VarA %in% c("a","c","e")
data$VarB[cond1] <- "yes"
cond2 <- data$VarA %in% c("b","d")
data$VarB[cond2] <- "no"
cond3 <- data$VarA %in% c("a","e")
data$VarC[cond3] <- 1
cond4 <- data$VarA %in% c("b","d")
data$VarC[cond4] <- 2
```

And I'll leave you to do the the last one yourself.

Comment: You can avoid `cond2` and `cond4` if you just do `!cond1` and `!cond3`, respectively. e.g. `data$VarB[!cond1] <- "no"`

Comment: Well yeah, but I assumed this as a general question, i.e. the nice property you mention might be only a coincidence.